# How do I get the directory from a file's full path?

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-io, directory

What is the simplest way to get the directory that a file is in? I'm using this to set a working directory.

```
string filename = @"C:\MyDirectory\MyFile.bat";
```

In this example, I should get "C:\MyDirectory".

Comment: Shouldn't that be a string literal? `@"C:\MyDirectory\MyFile.bat"`

Comment: Does somebody want to protect this question who has the rights to do so ? 11 similar answers with the last from 2017..

Answer (score 1034, accepted):

If you definitely have an absolute path, use [`Path.GetDirectoryName(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx).

If you might only have a relative name, use `new FileInfo(path).Directory.FullName`.

Note that `Path` and `FileInfo` are both found in the namespace `System.IO`.

Comment: Indeed, but is there a method called GetDirectory? Isn't it GetDirectoryName?

Comment: You can just use DirectoryName instead of Directory.FullPath can you not?

Comment: I was proofing against receiving a relative name. I hadn't spotted that the path will be absolute. I've now got both versions :)

Comment: Is there a single solution which works no matter the type of path we have? That is, be it either a relative or an absolute path.

Comment: @UlyssesAlves: I believe `new FileInfo(path).Directory.FullName` should work in either case.

Answer (score 72):

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filename)
```

Answer (score 26):

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName)`, or turn the path into a `FileInfo` using `FileInfo.Directory`.

If you're doing other things with the path, the `FileInfo` class may have advantages.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `Path.GetDirectoryName` and just pass in the filename.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

If you are working with a `FileInfo` object, then there is an easy way to extract a `string` representation of the directory's full path via the `DirectoryName` property.

Description of the `FileInfo.DirectoryName` Property via MSDN:

> Gets a string representing the directory's full path.

Sample usage:

```
string filename = @"C:\MyDirectory\MyFile.bat";
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filename);
string directoryFullPath = fileInfo.DirectoryName; // contains "C:\MyDirectory"
```

Link to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.directoryname.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You can get the current Application Path using:

```
string AssemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to use System.IO namespace. Then;

```
string filename = @"C:\MyDirectory\MyFile.bat";
string newPath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);
```

or

```
string newPath = Path.GetFullPath(openFileDialog1.FileName));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Path.GetFullPath` for most of the case.
But if you want to get the path also in the case of the file name is relatively located then you can use the below generic method:

```
string GetPath(string filePath)
{
  return Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetFullPath(filePath))
}
```

For example:

`GetPath("C:\Temp\Filename.txt")` return `"C:\Temp\"`

`GetPath("Filename.txt")` return `current working directory` like `"C:\Temp\"`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to find the directory name of a full path (of a directory) so I simply did:

```
var dirName = path.Split('\\').Last();
```

Comment: The OP needs `"C:\MyDirectory"` and not `MyDirectory`. The advice to use string manipulation methods is risky, there are many traps, rather use dedicated `Path` methods.