# How can I split names of directories in certain path from its full path (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

**Hello world!**

I've ran into a problem. I am getting directories contained in certain path and I need to separate the path VB.NET's giving me (like this:
"D:\ApplicationFolder\Addons\Pack_1",
"D:\ApplicationFolder\Addons\Pack_2" ...

Only into this:
"Pack_1", "Pack_2"

So far I've tried this, but I can't get into a solution, I am lost...

```
Dim ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORIES As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(ADDONS_PATH) ' GETTING ALL DIRECTORIES (PATHS) IN THIS PATH

    For Each ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORY In ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORIES ' TRYING TO SPLIT FULL PATH OF THESE DIRECTORIES TO GET ONLY THE NAME OF THESE DIRECTORIES

        ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORY.Split()

        Dim ADDONPACKS_LENGTH As Integer = ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORY.Length()
        MsgBox(ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORY(2))

    Next

    ' Here I want to assign names of these directories onto a label. But the fields only show letters instead of the path segments.

    Addonpack1.Text = ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORIES(0)
    Addonpack2.Text = ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORIES(1)
    Addonpack3.Text = ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORIES(2)
    Addonpack4.Text = ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORIES(3)
    Addonpack5.Text = ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORIES(4)
    'Addonpack6.Text = ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORY(5)
```

Any ideas? I really appreciate further help.

Comment: `ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORY(2)` You are asking for the third character in the string.

Comment: You probably just want `Dim s As String = Path.GetFileName(ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORY)`

Comment: There's no way this question wasn't asked before... yeah, i found some: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3736462, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5229292 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/3826763

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get folder name from full file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229292/get-folder-name-from-full-file-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[string.Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.String.Split);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) is a Function: it returns a value.

Here: `ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORY.Split()`, you are splitting the string using the default separator (a white space) but the result is not assigned to anything, so it's lost (but it wouldn't be useful anyway).

This: `MsgBox(ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORY(2))`, will show only one char of the current Directory path. A string is a collection (an array) of chars. You're asking to show the 3rd.

If you think you won't need the complete directory listing anymore, you could `Split` the initial collection directly:

```
Dim ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORIES As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(ADDONS_PATH).
    Select(Function(d) d.Split("\"c).Last()).ToArray()

Addonpack1.Text = ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORIES(0)
'(...)
```

If you instead are going to use that collection of Paths later, you could `Split` each path and assign the result to each `TextBox.Text` property, leaving the original collection untouched:

```
Addonpack1.Text = ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORIES(0).Split("\"c).Last()
Addonpack2.Text = ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORIES(1).Split("\"c).Last()
'(...)
```

Do you know beforehand how many Addons you will have?
If not, a TextBox for each path might not be the right object to use as the output.
Maybe, you could use a single multiline TextBox. It's [Lines()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.Lines);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) property will hold the array of all the Sub-Paths you appended.

Using the first snippet, it could be something like this:

```
For Each subpath As String In ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORIES
    TextBox1.AppendText(subpath & Environment.NewLine)
Next
```

**Note**:
As **LarsTech** noted in the comments, you could use [Path.GetFileName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.IO.Path.GetFileName);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) insted of splitting the path using the path separator.
It would work with both file names and path names, because `Path.GetFileName` returns the substring of a path when it first finds a path separator, parsing the string from the end to the start, no matter if the substring represents a path or a file name.

```
Addonpack1.Text = Path.GetFileName(ADDONPACKS_DIRECTORIES(0))
'(...)
```

Comment: `Path.GetFileName` does work in order to avoid all that split code.

Comment: @LarsTech  Yes, that's true. But I think it's more important, here, to show the use of Split (because of the way the OP is using it). `Path.GetFileName` can be, in this case, confusing, since we're dealing with paths and not file names. I'll leave a note if you think it's useful.