# How to get file path from OpenFileDialog and FolderBrowserDialog?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, folderbrowserdialog

Hey there i started learning C# a few days ago and I'm trying to make a program that copies and pastes files (and replaces if needed) to a selected directory but I don't know how to get the directory and file paths from the openfiledialog and folderbrowserdialog

what am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
namespace filereplacer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void direc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string folderPath = "";
            FolderBrowserDialog directchoosedlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (directchoosedlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                folderPath = directchoosedlg.SelectedPath;
            }
        }

        private void choof_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OpenFileDialog choofdlog = new OpenFileDialog();
            choofdlog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            choofdlog.FilterIndex = 1;

            choofdlog.Multiselect = true;
            choofdlog.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void replacebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          // This is where i'm having trouble
        }

        public static void ReplaceFile(string FileToMoveAndDelete, string FileToReplace, string BackupOfFileToReplace)
        {
            File.Replace(FileToMoveAndDelete, FileToReplace, BackupOfFileToReplace, false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is where to store the results from the two dialogs. The easiest way is to have two global variables in this form that you set with the value of OpenFileDialog.FileName and FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath. Then in your replace click event you could use the two variables (after some checks if they are set of course)

Comment: And this question title in inappropriate, because it is about basic concepts of object oriented languages like c#.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**For [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)**:

```
OpenFileDialog choofdlog = new OpenFileDialog();
choofdlog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
choofdlog.FilterIndex = 1;
choofdlog.Multiselect = true;

if (choofdlog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)    
{     
    string sFileName = choofdlog.FileName; 
    string[] arrAllFiles = choofdlog.FileNames; //used when Multiselect = true           
}
```

**For [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx)**:

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
fbd.Description = "Custom Description"; 

if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string sSelectedPath = fbd.SelectedPath;
}
```

To access `selected folder` and `selected file name` you can declare both string at **class level**.

```
namespace filereplacer
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      string sSelectedFile;
      string sSelectedFolder;

      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void direc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
         //fbd.Description = "Custom Description"; //not mandatory

         if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)      
               sSelectedFolder = fbd.SelectedPath;
         else
               sSelectedFolder = string.Empty;    
      }

      private void choof_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         OpenFileDialog choofdlog = new OpenFileDialog();
         choofdlog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
         choofdlog.FilterIndex = 1;
         choofdlog.Multiselect = true;

         if (choofdlog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)                 
             sSelectedFile = choofdlog.FileName;            
         else
             sSelectedFile = string.Empty;       
      }

      private void replacebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          if(sSelectedFolder != string.Empty && sSelectedFile != string.Empty)
          {
               //use selected folder path and file path
          }
      }
      ....
}
```

**NOTE**:

As you have kept `choofdlog.Multiselect=true;`, that means in the `OpenFileDialog()` you are able to select multiple files (by pressing `ctrl` key and left mouse click for selection).

In that case you could get all selected files in `string[]`:

At Class Level:

```
string[] arrAllFiles;
```

Locate this line (when `Multiselect=true` this line gives first file only):

```
sSelectedFile = choofdlog.FileName;
```

To get all files use this:

```
arrAllFiles = choofdlog.FileNames; //this line gives array of all selected files
```

Answer (score 12):

Use the `Path` class from `System.IO`. It contains useful calls for manipulating file paths, including `GetDirectoryName` which does what you want, returning the directory portion of the file path.

Usage is simple.

```
string directoryPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(choofdlog.FileName);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can store the Path into string variable like

```
string s = choofdlog.FileName;
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the full file path of a selected file or files, then you need to use [FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) property for one file or [FileNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames(v=vs.110).aspx) property for multiple files.

```
var file = choofdlog.FileName; // for one file
```

or for multiple files

```
var files = choofdlog.FileNames; // for multiple files.
```

To get the directory of the file, you can use [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx)
Here is Jon Keet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/674495/547639) to a similar question about getting directories from path

Comment: SelectedFile? SelectedFiles? Where did you find these properties in an OpenFileDialog instance?

Comment: @Steve Sorry, it is a spelling mistake. I wanted to write FileName and FileNames. I linked it to the proper properties links though. Thanks, I will edit my post.

Answer (score 2):

Create this class as Extension:

```
public static class Extensiones
{
    public static string FolderName(this OpenFileDialog ofd)
    {
            string resp = "";
            resp = ofd.FileName.Substring(0, 3);
            var final = ofd.FileName.Substring(3);
            var info = final.Split('\\');
            for (int i = 0; i < info.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                resp += info[i] + "\\";
            }
            return resp;
    }
}
```

Then, you could use in this way:

```
        //ofdSource is an OpenFileDialog 
        if (ofdSource.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ofdSource.FolderName());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `choofdlog` holds a `FileName` and `FileNames` (for multi-selection) containing the file paths, after the `ShowDialog()` returns.

Answer (score 1):

A primitive quick fix that works.

If you only use `OpenFileDialog`, you can capture the `FileName`, `SafeFileName`, then subtract to get folder path:

```
exampleFileName = ofd.SafeFileName;
exampleFileNameFull = ofd.FileName;
exampleFileNameFolder = ofd.FileNameFull.Replace(ofd.FileName, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry if i am late to reply here but i just thought i should throw in a much simpler solution for the OpenDialog.

```
OpenDialog ofd = new OpenDialog();
var fullPathIncludingFileName = ofd.Filename; //returns the full path including the filename
var fullPathExcludingFileName = ofd.Filename.Replace(ofd.SafeFileName, "");//will remove the filename from the full path
```

I have not yet used a FolderBrowserDialog before so i will trust my fellow coders's take on this. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
String fn = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
String path = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString().Replace(fn, "");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Isn't this a variation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43357913/1364007)? Please don't post duplicate answers. If your answer to an old question is new and different, explain how it's different.