# C# using Windows File Explorer to set selected file to string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, windows, forms, file

I'm starting a new project, and I need to be able to save/load users data.

I want them to click a button, then this brings up a file explorer where they select their .txt file. This .txt file then needs to be stored in a string array, where I can then manipulate the data.

If someone could point me in the right direction of what tools to use, that would be great. I've looked at OpenFileDialog, but I don't see how to assign it to an array.

Comment: Do you want a tutorial for working with the txt file? writing and reading data from it?

Comment: If there's one already going that'd be good, if not don't worry.

Comment: Have a look at some of these sections they should be helpful going forward https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzb96fk.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're just looking for [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines) - once you've got the filename, of courses. You need to separate out the tasks of "let the user select a file" from "read the contents of the file".

`OpenFileDialog` is probably the right tool to use for the first part, then `File.ReadAllLines` for the second...

Comment: Ahh yes I have used File.ReadAllLines before, but what I don't know is how to use the File explorer to set the path to a variable?

Comment: @OliSmart: Well, you've looked at `OpenFileDialog` - did you not see anything in the documentation and the example that might tell you which file the user selected?

Comment: @OliSmart Take a look to get file path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449988/how-to-get-file-path-from-openfiledialog-and-folderbrowserdialog