# how to get full path of D://folder name?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Kindly help to get file path from D drive.
how to get path as like it is "D:\Folder\Reports\DAILY REPORT\new.docx".
Any one help me ?

Comment: what have you tried so far? are you trying to access files in server side or client side?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674479/how-do-i-get-the-directory-from-a-files-full-path
There is an example.
Look for the Path library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not complete but if you want resolve virtual paths and physical paths you can use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`

For example:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reports/DAILY REPORT/new.docx");
```

But i don't know what you want exactly.