# Application won't save file to path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get a file upload to work in an application I'm developing.

On my local machine I've been using the following to save the file to a folder on a shared resource:

```
string path = Path.Combine("\\appname\myfolder$", Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
file.SaveAs(path);
```

and everything works fine.

(On the 'appname' server, the folder 'myfolder' is in the root (e.g.) c:\myfolder)

When I deploy my project to IIS on the same server (e.g. http:\appname) this no longer works.

As a result I tried to change the code to point to the c drive on the server it would be running from e.g.

```
string path = Path.Combine("c:\\myfolder", Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                    file.SaveAs(path);
```

and this didn't work either.  Tried a few other things but now lost it completely.  Can anybody help?

Comment: you need to use Server.MapPath to get the physical path to where you want to save, and the app pool identity has to have write permissions to that path.

Comment: You might want to check if the file exists first before using `file.FileName`.

Comment: What about the user running IIS? Does it have the right permissions?

Comment: Also, you can get the file directory directly from the file via `Path.GetDirectoryname` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674479/how-do-i-get-the-directory-from-a-files-full-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running this application in IIS, assign an authorized user to the application context, that is hosting the website.
By default the worker is running in system context and the operating system (machine account) would require access to the share - which is really not a recommendet solution.

See [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) how to configure the application pool identity.