# Convert absolute image path to URL in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I developed an application in MVC 3 in which i stored the images on the server at C drive and in Images Folder.

My Web Application is working fine.

Now we are developing an application in Store Apps in which we 'll have to give the absolute path into the following url.

http://www.asp.net/images/a.png.

How can i convert it like this ?

Guide please so that i 'll not have to convert my whole structure of image saving.

Comment: may be it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674479/how-do-i-get-the-directory-from-a-files-full-path

Comment: thank u shamim but this 'll not help in my case