# Get folder by an absolute path

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, io

I have a console App (dotnet core)

```
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        string Folder = @"‪C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/local-folder";
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(Folder);
        bool isExist = Directory.Exists(Folder);
        bool isExist2 = d.Exists;
```

The issue is that `isExist` and `isExist2` take always `false` even the folder exists !

It seems that , each time, the folder path is considered as a relative path.

So how can I fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps a permission problem?

Comment: @Steve no :) i have permissions to access and even i take another folder i have the same error

Comment: just to be sure try with just @"‪string Folder = C:/Users";  what is the result?

Comment: What about slashes,C:\Users\... instead of C:/Users/...?

Comment: @shev72 sorry I don't understand what do u mean

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski : same result :(

Comment: false because the values is empty. If you print `d` what it gives you?

Comment: I mean just try to use the first part of the path rather than the whole path  (just to confirm any specific issues with .../Desktop/local-folder )  I tested @"C:/Users" also with backslah @"C:\Users"  and works on my machine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the directory from a file's full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674479/how-do-i-get-the-directory-from-a-files-full-path)

Comment: @Syafiqur : d  all properties are throwing an exception and refers to a relative path under the app folder

Comment: path should be : `@"‪C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\local-folder"`

Comment: I have copied your path above in Notepad++ and looked at it in Hex format. There are some invisible characters before the C letter. Exactly _e2 80 aa_  Try to rewrite the path directly on your code without copying it from some other source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the path following way:

```
string Folder = @"‪C:\\Users\Admin\Desktop\local-folder"
```

The following outputs true for me in .net core 2.2 application:

```
string Folder = @"C:\\Users\ehsan.sajjad\Source\Repos\order-processor\Src";
System.IO.DirectoryInfo d = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Folder);
bool isExist = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Folder); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be working fine. The only problem there is your path.If you have copied it then Try rewriting the path on your own.  As mentioned by @steve there are some invisible characters in your path.